# Spring batch with scoped beans and AllowBeanDefinitionOverriding=false

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-aop

I want to use scoped spring batch beans

```
 <bean id="processor"
 class="com.example.Processor"  
 p:type="#{jobParameters['type']}"
 scope="step"/>
```

and AllowBeanDefinitionOverriding = false

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
context.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
context.load("myResource.xml", "otherResource.xml");
context.refresh();
```

How to avoid BeanDefinitionStoreException with Spring version 4.2.4.RELEASE

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'xxx' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [yyyy]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [yyyy]] for bean 'xxx': There is already [Generic bean: class [xxxProcessor]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [yyyy]] bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.BatchScopeSupport.createScopedProxy(BatchScopeSupport.java:159)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.BatchScopeSupport.postProcessBeanFactory(BatchScopeSupport.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
```

or the same with Spring version 3.1.4.RELEASE

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.BatchScopeSupport.createScopedProxy(BatchScopeSupport.java:159)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.BatchScopeSupport.postProcessBeanFactory(BatchScopeSupport.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:670)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full stack traces?

Comment: Hi, Michael! Glad to see you. There is nothing special in full stacktrace. I cleared possible sensitive data from my employer. But I'll try to create small sample project to show this behavior in action and maybe create feature request in tracker. I plan to do it tomorrow.

Comment: Motivation for this feature request: We have a big complex app with sprng-batch, spring-integration and core spring with about 2000 components in 30 config files. App is actively developed by 3-5 developers. Sometimes we have collision in bean names from different configs and related issues. So we want to prevent bean definition overriding

Comment: Given some of the magic that batch does behind the scenes...that may cause more pain than it's worth.

Comment: It may be a better solution to use child application contexts.

Comment: @Artefacto, seems it's true. It's better to separate batch and non-batch context and load above with different AllowBeanDefinitionOverriding settings