# JobScope and overriding beans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am attempting to upgrade a spring batch job to spring boot 2.1.x.
I have beans that use the "Job" scope. After upgrading I'm getting an error
     The bean ..., could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined ... and overriding is disabled.

I can set the property
     spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
and make it past the error.

My question is do I always need set this property if I use Job or Step scope?

Full Error Message:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'reportWriterListener' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [jobs/base_config.xml]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [jobs/base_config.xml]] for bean 'reportWriterListener': There is already [Generic bean: class [com.zionsbancorp.spring.batch.batch.ReportWriterJobListener]; scope=job; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [jobs/base_config.xml]] bound.
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'reportWriterListener' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [jobs/base_config.xml]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [jobs/base_config.xml]] for bean 'reportWriterListener': There is already [Generic bean: class [com.zionsbancorp.spring.batch.batch.ReportWriterJobListener]; scope=job; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [jobs/base_config.xml]] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.BatchScopeSupport.createScopedProxy(BatchScopeSupport.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.BatchScopeSupport.postProcessBeanFactory(BatchScopeSupport.java:130) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.zbc.zci.aspirercif.Application.main(Application.java:48) [classes/:na]
```

Config Snippet

```
    <bean id="reportWriterListener" class="com.zbc.spring.batch.batch.ReportWriterJobListener" scope="job">
        <constructor-arg value="${report.file}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Which bean can not be registered? The error could be related a bean other than your job scoped bean, like the transaction manager for instance (probably your are facing [BATCH-2788](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2788)) or any other infrastructure bean), so please share the full stacktrace of the error to understand the issue.

Comment: Hey Mahmoud,
Thanks for taking a look.
I've added detail to the original post including full error message, error stack trace, and the corresponding configuration.

Comment: looks like you have two bean definitions for `reportWriterListener`. Are you sure there is only one bean definition for that type?

Comment: Yes there is only one and removing the scope attribute eliminates this issue.
(although there is a reason I want this bean to be job scoped)

Comment: Similar question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498037/spring-batch-with-scoped-beans-and-allowbeandefinitionoverriding-false